# Dependency inversion (IOC) of third party singleton

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns, singleton, inversion-of-control

I have difficulties implementing inversion of control in order to keep loose coupling between my modules, and also preventing dependency cycle.

In my example I want to dynamically register configuration for a third party library (Apollo Client).

### Current implementation

With my current implementation, I have dependency cycle issues

**Folder structure**

```js
src
├── apolloClient.ts
├── modules
│   ├── messages
│   │   ├── ui.ts
│   │   └── state.ts
│   ├── users
│   │   ├── ui.ts
│   │   └── state.ts
...
```

**apolloClient.ts**

```js
import { InMemoryCache, ApolloClient } from '@apollo/client'
import { messagesTypePolicies } from './modules/messages/state.ts'
import { usersTypePolicies } from './modules/users/state.ts'

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Query: {
        // register manually all modules
        ...messagesTypePolicies,
        ...usersTypePolicies
      }
    }
  }),
})
```

**modules/messages/state.ts**

```js
import { client } from '../../apolloClient.ts'

export const messagesTypePolicies = {
  messagesList: {
    read() {
      return ['hello', 'yo']
    }
  }
}

export const updateMessage = () => {
  client.writeQuery(...) // Use of client, so here we have a dependency cycle issue
}
```

### What I would like

To prevent dependency cycle and tight coupling, I would like each module to register itself,
so that the `apolloClient` singleton has no dependency on UI modules.

**modules/messages/state.ts**

```js
import { client, registerTypePolicies } from '../../apolloClient.ts'

// Use custom function to register typePolicies on UI modules
registerTypePolicies({
  messagesList: {
    read() {
      return ['hello', 'yo']
    }
  }
})

export const updateMessage = () => {
  client.writeQuery(...) // Dependency cycle issue solved :)
}
```

**apolloClient.ts**

```js
export const registerTypePolicies = () => {
  // What I am trying to solve using IOC pattern
  // Not sure how to dynamically update the singleton
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Apollo to answer this properly.  It looks like all of the configurations for `ApolloClient` and `InMemoryCache` are created by passing configurations when you call `new` so I'm not sure if you can modify them after the fact.  You might want to go the other direction, where messages doesn't depend on the client.  You can make `updateMessage` be a function of `client` and pass in the client when you call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a lot of experience with the `ApolloClient`, but it looks as though the settings for `ApolloClient` and `InMemoryCache` are created by passing configurations when you call `new`.  My concern is that you might not be able to modify them after the fact.  For this reason, I propose that you `import` your modules into the client file rather than the other way around.

Of course you will have methods in your modules which depend on the `client` instance, but we can make them be functions which take the `client` as an argument.  That allows us to write the methods before the client has been created.

I came up with a design based on the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). We define each module as an `object` with two properties: `policies` is a key-value object of policy definitions, fitting the `TypePolicies` type from the apollo package; `makeMethods` is a function which takes the `client` and returns a key-value object of functions.  We use that returned functions object as the generic for the interface so that we can get the exact definitions for the function later on.

```
type MethodFactory<MethodMap> = (
  client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>
) => MethodMap;

interface Module<MethodMap> {
  policies: TypePolicies;
  makeMethods: MethodFactory<MethodMap>;
}
```

When we build the methods into a `client`, we will pass all of the policies to the `cache`.  We will also pass the newly created `client` to the `makeMethods` factory and return methods which no longer require the `client` because it has already been injected.

Let me pause here to say that something is not quite right with the `policies` portion of my code as I don't fully understand what a policy is supposed to look like.  So I'll leave that up to you to figure out. ([docs link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#typepolicy-fields))

Our `Builder` starts with no settings.  Each time that we add a module, we combine the settings with the existing and return a new `Builder`.  Eventually we call `build` which returns an object with two properties: `client` which is the `ApolloClient` and `methods` which is an object of methods that are bound to the client.

```
class Builder<MethodMap> {
  policies: TypePolicies;
  makeMethods: MethodFactory<MethodMap>;

  protected constructor(module: Module<MethodMap>) {
    this.makeMethods = module.makeMethods;
    this.policies = module.policies;
  }

  public static create(): Builder<{}> {
    return new Builder({ makeMethods: () => ({}), policies: {} });
  }

  public addModule<AddedMethods>(
    module: Module<AddedMethods>
  ): Builder<MethodMap & AddedMethods> {
    return new Builder({
      policies: {
        ...this.policies,
        ...module.policies
      },
      makeMethods: (client) => ({
        ...this.makeMethods(client),
        ...module.makeMethods(client)
      })
    });
  }

  public build(): {
    client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>;
    methods: MethodMap;
  } {
    const client = new ApolloClient({
      cache: new InMemoryCache({
        typePolicies: this.policies
      })
    });
    const methods = this.makeMethods(client);

    return { client, methods };
  }
}
```

Usage looks like this:

```
const messagesModule = {
  policies: {
    messagesList: {
      read() {
        return ["hello", "yo"];
      }
    } as TypePolicy // I don't know enough about TypePolicies to understand why this is needed
  },
  makeMethods: (client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>) => ({
    updateMessage: (): void => {
      client.writeQuery({});
    }
  })
};

// some dummy data
const otherModule = {
  policies: {},
  makeMethods: (client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>) => ({
    doSomething: (): number => {
      return 5;
    },
    somethingElse: (arg: string): void => {}
  })
};

// build through chaining
const { client, methods } = Builder.create()
  .addModule(messagesModule)
  .addModule(otherModule)
  .build();

// can call a method without any arguments
methods.updateMessage();

// methods with arguments know their correct argument type
methods.somethingElse('');

// can call any method on the client
const resolvers = client.getResolvers();

// can destructure methods from the map object
const {updateMessage, doSomething, somethingElse} = methods;
```

You would export the `client` from here and use it throughout your app.

You could destructure `methods` and export methods individually, or you could just export the whole `methods` object.  Note that you cannot have methods with the same names in multiple modules because they are not nested.

Comment: Thank for your clear answer ! Finally I end up with something really similar to your solution. As you've said, the idea is to export a "builder" class than handle the instanciation of the Apollo client class.